# problema con variable que viene NULL , reemplazar por cero

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una variable que en casos viene con valor "NULL" 
y cuando es "NULL" necesito convertirla a "0", 
para que cuando me grabe ese dato en la base de datos lo haga con "0" y no con "NULL"

desde donde obtengo el dato:

```
 $query = "SELECT 
           SUM( T.DAT1 * T.DAT2 ) AS 'TOTAL'
           FROM TAB1 T";
```

el while:

```
                while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){
                $tot   = $row['TOTAL'];
                if ($tot == "" )
                    { 
                    $tot = 0;
                    }
```

el update del dato en la tabla:

```
     $update = "UPDATE TAB1 SET CAMPO1 = ".$tot."";
```

el problema es que no me reemplaza por cero los nulos, siguen quedando como nulos...

el tipo de dato "CAMPO1" es un (decimal de 11 , 2) , no creo que el problema eso.

también intente con :

```
  $tot = empty( $row['TOTAL'] ) ? 0 : (float) $row['TOTAL'];
```

y nada..

tambien intente con:

```
  $update = "UPDATE TAB1 SET CAMPO1 = IFNULL(".$tot.",0)";
```

y nada...

TABLA:

```
  CREATE TABLE `TAB1` (
  `CAMPO1` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL
   ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AVG_ROW_LENGTH=160
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrarnos la constitución de la tabla, basta con ejecutar esta consulta en el manejador: `SHOW CREATE TABLE TAB1`? Muchas veces `0` es interpretado como `NULL` según el contexto.

Comment: @A.Cedano adjunte arriba la tabla...

Comment: Habría que revisar lo que se crea en `$tot`, mediante un  `var_dump($tot);`, pero debo decirte que esto lo puedes resolver de raíz, mediante un: `ALTER TABLE TAB1 MODIFY COLUMN CAMPO1 decimal(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0` esto hará que siempre que se intente insertar un valor `NULL` en la tabla, o si se ignora el campo en una inserción, esta columna adquiera el valor `0`.  Para normalizar los datos que ya hay puedes hacer esto: `UPDATE TAB1 SET CAMPO1 =0 WHERE CAMPO1 IS NULL` Con eso resuelves el problema de una forma definitiva. Si de todos modos quieres saber por qué no funciona en PHP...

Comment: ... dinos cuál de todos los `UPDATE` es el que usas, porque muestras varios, y dinos qué arroja la prueba de la variable que estás manejando. No obstante, no resuelvas por programación cosas que la base de datos hace mucho mejor, mediante definiciones como las que te muestro en el otro comentario. Además, con una definición así, no estás obligado a usar el campo en las inserciones siempre. Supongamos un contexto donde haya que insertar otros datos y no ese, si omites el campo, adquirirá el valor `0`, mientras que del otro modo tendrás que asignarle `0` obligatoriamente.

Comment: @A.Cedano el es primer update, el otro que pongo es un intento que hago pero tampoco lo deja a nulo, creo que la mejor opción es hacer lo que dices, dejar el dato en DEFAULT 0 directamente en la tabla...

Comment: Sí y en cuanto a PHP, cuando tengas problemas con una variable, usa `var_dump`, por ejemplo puedes probar lo que hay en la variable con `var_dump($tot);` o en el dato directamente con `var_dump($row['TOTAL']);` a veces el dato no está vacío, puede tener por ejemplo espacios en blanco y cosas así. En el resultado del var_dump debes fijarte por eso en la extensión y el valor de los elementos. Por último, considera el uso de consultas preparadas para el `UPDATE`, tu código corre un serio riesgo de *inyección SQL* tal y como lo estás usando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo optaría por dar una solución definitiva al problema, normalizando los datos en la base de datos misma.

En este caso la normalización es muy simple, en dos pasos no intercambiables, primero el paso 1 luego el 2:

1. Cambiar todos los valores `NULL` actuales por `0` mediante esta consulta:

   ```
   UPDATE TAB1 
       SET CAMPO1 = 0 
   WHERE CAMPO1 IS NULL
   ```
2. Cambiar la definición de la columna en la tabla para que **de ahora en adelante no admita nulos, y adquiera por defecto el valor `0`**:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE TAB1 
       MODIFY COLUMN CAMPO1 decimal(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
   ```

Con esa configuración no tienes que preocuparte de nada más, no romperte el coco queriendo resolver por progamación algo que el manejador de base de datos hace muchísimo mejor.

Por ejemplo, cada vez que se intente insertar `NULL` en ese campo lo cambiará por `0`.  Y si en alguna consulta `INSERT` no vas a insertar valores en `CAMPO1`, simplemente lo omites en la consulta y en las nuevas filas ese valor será `0`. En cambio, si no tienes una definición adecuada para la columnas, siempre tendrás que estar convirtiendo valores para luego ponérselos como `0` en la columna.

En cuanto a PHP, cuando algo no te funcione, haz uso de un gran amigo desconocido, se llama `var_dump`. Cuando algo no funcione, pásalo por `var_dump($elDatoProblematico);` y analízalo. Esta función te devuelve el contenido, tipo, tamaño de los objetos. A veces un dato no está vacío, porque tiene espacios en blanco y cosas así, o es un booleano `TRUE`, `var_dump` revelará muchos secretos que a veces hacen que pierdas horas depurando un código.

Comment: el dato no viene corrupto, debido que al hacer un 'select count(*) from TAB1 where CAMPO1 IS NULL' Me indica la cantidad de NULOS que existen en en el campo.. normalizare le campo y te indico como me fue...

Comment: @FranciscoAcevedo pero ¿qué muestra el `var_dump` del campo? Otra cosa es que tu `UPDATE` no tiene ningún criterio ni nada. No puedes lanzar un `UPDATE` al aire, sin ningún tipo de criterio de búsqueda, es peligroso.

Comment: Opte por Normalizar la tabla, gracias ;)

Answer (score 1):

Usa la funcion coalesce en tu query inicial directamente asi te evitas arrastrar el problema en tu código.

```
 $query = "SELECT 
       COALESCE(SUM( T.DAT1 * T.DAT2 ), 0) AS 'TOTAL'
       FROM TAB1 T";
```

La funcion coalesce devuelve el primer resultado no nulo de los pasados. En tu caso si el valor de tu suma no es nulo lo devolvera y si no devolvera 0 que es el siguiente valor no nulo.

[API oficial de MySQL sobre Coalesce](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

Comment: no estimado, no convierte el dato a 0

Comment: Si `SUM( T.DAT1 * T.DAT2 )` vale NULL ya te digo que `TOTAL` va a valer 0 si o si.

Comment: en el motor de base de datos talves si, por php no lo hace...

Comment: Php no tiene que convertir nada ya le viene el valor a 0.

Comment: pues no lo esta haciendo :(

Comment: Pues entonces es porque estas recuperando mal el valor. Prueba a poner TOTAL sin comillas en la query inicial.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89435/discussion-between-francisco-acevedo-and-jdev).

Comment: en el update deje la variable $tot  y tampoco